# Sails can't distinguish GET from POST in routes.js?

Tags: sails.js

I was looking at sails and building some simple user auth app with it. Routes were written in config/routes.js:

```
  'GET /signup': {view:'signup'},
  'POST /signup':'UserController.signup'
```

But when I make a POST request *localhost:1337/signup*, I getting view in response (Chrome - > Network shows that). Have no idea what I did wrong there.

Can you help me?

Code from api/controllers/UserController.js:

```
module.exports = {      
    signup: function(req, res){
            console.log('Please, be in console');
    }
}
```

Angular code:

```
angular.module('SignupMod').controller('SignupCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  console.log('Signup Controller Started');

  $scope.runSignup = function(){
    console.log('Signing Up ' + $scope.name);

    //Submit to Sails Server
    $http.post('/signup', {
        name: $scope.name,
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    })
    .then(function onSuccess(response){
        console.log('Success!');
    })
    .catch(function onError(err){
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    })
  }
}])
```

Comment: are you signing up via ajax or direct post???

Comment: Ajax post request (via Angular $http.post)

Comment: in networks do see that post reqquest or there is the get request??

Comment: better you add your angular code here!

Comment: Angular code added to question. Do anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: in networks do you see that post request or there is the get request??

Comment: Post request, but sails keep responding with view. Screenshots from Chrome dev tools - http://imgur.com/a/9Pu7w

Comment: make sure your route is 
`'GET /signup': {view:'signup'},
 'POST /signup':'UserController.signup'`

Comment: http://imgur.com/RczHbiy - exactly like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was something with sails installiation on my local machine.

After re-installing, all worked as it should. (in both cases, I've installed sails with "-g" in npm)